# Comment out a string in HTML before UIWebView can display it

Tags: objective-c, ios

Since I do not quite understand how the HTML is read before the page is displayed, is it possible for ObjC to search for a string in the head of a HTML document and then comment it out if the string is present before the HTML opens in a UIWebView?

If so, can you give a snippet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build your HTML string however you want to, and then set it to the UIWebView like this:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

As for parsing the string itself, NSMutableString has a nifty method that will help out a lot. This is what I use:

```
[html replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"<div>Hello</div>" withString:@"<!--div>Hello</div-->" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [html length])];
```

So if there is something that you are consistently looking for, you can replace it with something that is commented out and then set that to the webView.

Hope that helps!